# why my image gallery is not closing

Tags: html, css

I am making a image gallery with fancy box with title, but when i click on image, the image is opening but can not close the image or can not find a close button. I am using html , css and javascript . I am uploading a image to show what is my problem.

[image: this is my image]
[image: image gallery]

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //FANCYBOX
    //https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        openEffect: "none",
        closeEffect: "none"
    });
});
```

html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" media="screen">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='list-group gallery'>
            <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
                <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="http://placehold.it/300x320.png">
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/320x320" />
                    <div class='text-right'>
                        <small class='text-muted'>Image Title</small>
                    </div> <!-- text-right / end -->
                </a>
            </div> <!-- col-6 / end -->
            <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
                <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="http://placehold.it/300x320.png">
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/320x320" />
                    <div class='text-right'>
                        <small class='text-muted'>Image Title</small>
                    </div> <!-- text-right / end -->
                </a>
            </div> <!-- col-6 / end -->
            <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
                <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="http://placehold.it/300x320.png">
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/320x320" />
                    <div class='text-right'>
                        <small class='text-muted'>Image Title</small>
                    </div> <!-- text-right / end -->
                </a>
            </div> <!-- col-6 / end -->
            <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
                <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="http://placehold.it/300x320.png">
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/320x320" />
                    <div class='text-right'>
                        <small class='text-muted'>Image Title</small>
                    </div> <!-- text-right / end -->
                </a>
            </div> <!-- col-6 / end -->
            <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
                <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="http://placehold.it/300x320.png">
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/320x320" />
                    <div class='text-right'>
                        <small class='text-muted'>Image Title</small>
                    </div> <!-- text-right / end -->
                </a>
            </div> <!-- col-6 / end -->
            <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
                <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="http://placehold.it/300x320.png">
                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/320x320" />
                    <div class='text-right'>
                        <small class='text-muted'>Image Title</small>
                    </div> <!-- text-right / end -->
                </a>
            </div> <!-- col-6 / end -->
        </div> <!-- list-group / end -->
    </div> <!-- row / end -->
</div> <!-- container / end -->
```

css

```
.gallery
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Any JS errors in Developer Console?

Answer (score 0):

You have links pointing to images in your html, which should be causing the issue. It's opening the image in a new page, not the desired gallery

```
<a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="http://placehold.it/300x320.png">
```

try using other element or removing the href attribute